# Uttara Gita: Source of Uttara Gita in Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, gita

Which part of Mahabharata contains: Uttara Gita. https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/uttara-gita-idk878/

I don't see the exact Mahabharata verses for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your question, I gather after searching that the sources are in the Mahabharat, but it is not a direct subsection of it.

Technically:Uttaragītā (उत्तरगीता) as mentioned in Aufrecht’s Catalogus Catalogorum:—three chapters said to be taken from the Bhīṣmaparvan. Hall. p. 122. L. 933. K. 34 (and—[commentary]). B. 4, 46. Tu7b. 6. Haug. 46. Burnell. 186^b. P. 9. Oppert. 2771. Ii, 1035. 2423. 2790. 3594. 6209. 7352. 8169. Rice. 136. Peters. 1, 113. Bp. 271.
—[commentary] Rādh. 25. NW. 280.
—[commentary] by Gauḍapāda. Hall. p. 123. L. 189. 2144. Ben. 60. 68. Burnell. 186^b. Oppert. 1767. 3762. 4930. Ii, 1926. 6210. 6536. 6744. 7353. Rice. 136. Peters. 1, 113.

Comment: Can you please cite the exact sources from the Internet? I don't think that the majority of the Mahabharata versions on the internet does contain that.

Comment: You will find it the references to Uttaragita in wisdomlib.

Comment: Can you link that particular wisdomlib page in case you find it? It would be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: Most welcome . It is a bit down the page...https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/uttaragita